# How to add numbers and put results into an array

Tags: javascript, php

I have used one fro condition and added `85` with `1` and added result again with `1`;
ie.,

```
85+1=86
86+1=87
87+1=88
```

I need all `85,86,87,88` to be put in one array???

how to call them into one array

Comment: You want it in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a sequential array that start from a certain number with certain number of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304904/creating-a-sequential-array-that-start-from-a-certain-number-with-certain-number)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in JavaScript

```js
var arr = Array(3) // create array of size 3
  .fill(86) // fill it with 86
  .map(function(v, i) {
    return v + i // iterate and update value 
  });

document.write(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple loop you can do this.

```
$array = array();
$n = 85; // the start number
$limit = 88; // The max value to reach
while($n <= $limit) {
    // increment by 1 and store into array
    $n++;
    $array[] = $n; 
}
```

If increment needs to be another value then -

```
$array = array();
$n = 85; // the start number
$limit = 88; // The max value to reach
$increment = 2;
while($n <= $limit) {
    // increment by 1 and store into array
    $n += $increment;
    $array[] = $n; 
}
```

Comment: no this is not working, only last value is being added to array, I need all 85,86,87,88 to be in one array, here only 88 is coming

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var = 85;
$array =array();
$array[0]=$var;
for($i=1;$i<=3; $i++)
{
    $array[$i]=$array[$i-1]+1;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

```
$range = range(85, 88);
```

#### In depth

The tag `PHP` is attached to your question so I assume I can use PHP to form my answer.

The `range()` function will make your life alot easier. It will assign a range of numbers, letters etc. to an array without having to loop.

```
// Create the array
$numberArray = range(1, 100);

// Create an alphabetic array
$alphaArray = range('a', 'z');

var_dump($numberArray);

// Output
array(
    [0] => 1,
    [1] => 2,
    [2] => 3,
    [3] => 4,
    ...
    [99] => 100
)
```

In your case that would be:

```
$range = range(85, 88);

// Output
array(
    [0] => 85
    [1] => 86
    [2] => 87
    [3] => 88
)
```

I hope this will help you out a bit

### Sources

[PHP.net - range() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is also an alternative solution

```
$array = array();
$n = 85; //The start number
$limit = 88; //The max value to reach
while($n <= $limit) {
    //Increment by 1 and store into array
    $n++;
    array_push($array,$n); 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
 [0] => 86
 [1] => 87
 [2] => 88
 [3] => 89
)
```

Comment: Then can you please accept my answer. :) @sivasanker

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be useful

```
 var _initArray = [85];
 function _myArray(add_times,array){
 for(var i =0;i<=add_times;i++){
    //will give index of last element
    //_initArray[_initArray.length-1] will return last element
    var _getElem = _initArray[_initArray.length-1];
    //Add 1 with last element. 
    var _newElem = _getElem+1;
    _initArray.push(_newElem);
 }
 console.log(_initArray);
}
_myArray(5,_initArray);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/30vugo8g/1/)