# Creating a sequential array that start from a certain number with certain number of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there an elegant way (without a for loop) to create a sequential array in Javascript which starts from a certain number and has a certain numbers of items. for example:

Start from **2017** and has **4** items will look like:

```
[2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a callback for the values.

> The **`Array.from()`** method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.
>
> [...]
>
> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to execute a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on each element of the array (or subclass object) that is being created. More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array. This is especially important for certain array subclasses, like [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), since the intermediate array would necessarily have values truncated to fit into the appropriate type.

```js
var items = 4,
    start = 2017,
    array = Array.from({ length: items }, (_, i) => start + i);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I just realized, `new Array(n).map((x,i)=>i)` does not returns values but `map` of `Array.from` does. Another WTF in JS

Comment: @Rajesh, you get a sparse array with `new Array(n)`. `map` does not work with missing items.